# What NPM dependencies are required for modular Vue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, vue.js, npm

I have working knowledge in conventional multi page applications developed in HTML + JS libraries using SSR but I am new to modern web development. I am currently learning Vue JS (the latest version) and I have watched some tutorial videos online. The videos I watched taught writing Vue JS web pages in a plain HTML + `<script>` setup instead of a project setup created by a Vue CLI program.

Now, I would like to know what NPM dependencies in the **package.json** file are required to change a project setup from a single HTML + Vue CDN script src to one with a folder structure set up by `vue-cli`, just like modern project folder structure created by other CLIs, e.g. Angular and React.

After running `vue init <template name>` I get a **package.json** like the following:

```
{
    ...,
    "scripts": {
      "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
      "start": "npm run dev",
      "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
      "build": "node build/build.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "vue": "^2.5.2",
      "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
      "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
      "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
      "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
      "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
      "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
      "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
      "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
      "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
      "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
      "chalk": "^2.0.1",
      "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
      "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
      "eslint": "^4.15.0",
      "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
      "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
      "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
      "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
      "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
      "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
      "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
      "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
      "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
      "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
      "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
      "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
      "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
      "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
      "ora": "^1.2.0",
      "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
      "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
      "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
      "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
      "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
      "semver": "^5.3.0",
      "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
      "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
      "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
      "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
      "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
      "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
      "webpack": "^3.6.0",
      "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
      "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
    },
    "engines": {
      "node": ">= 6.0.0",
      "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
    },
    "browserslist": [
      "> 1%",
      "last 2 versions",
      "not ie <= 8"
    ]
}
```

In this NPM project, it is not required to have a `<script src>` CDN link but I am still able to use all Vue features. I know the JavaScript file is already included in one of the `node_modules` folders. But what makes the HTML files to load the script from the folder/sub-folder/sub-sub-folder? I do not find any file path pointing to the JS file(s) in the project.

In Vue's official documentation, it states that:

> The Installation page provides more options of installing Vue. Note: We do not recommend that beginners start with vue-cli, especially if you are not yet familiar with Node.js-based build tools.

May I know what dependencies do the job (or if it is the nature of a Node.js project, it is born this way) and any documentation or quotes from developers that are easy to understand for web dev newbies like me?

Answer (score 0):

> But what makes the HTML files to load the script from the folder/sub-folder/sub-sub-folder?

I think what you're looking for is [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) [config](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html) - I suggest you when creating blank project via Vue-CLI select options manually to set each config in dedicated file (so e.g. webpack's one will be in `webpack` folder with different `.config.js` files (separately for development, common and production). 
Webpack resolves for you all file paths and dependencies that are used inside your project and bundles them into one (or multiple part-chunk) JavaScript file.

Regarding your main question - what you see under `dependencies` section is what will be included in your final application code and is necessary to make it work. Although, what you have under `devDependencies` section is required to build/compile/transpile/minify etc. your project so in the end it will have all dependency paths resolved properly, styles compiled (e.g. from scss to css) and everything uglyfied + minified.